# Citrix .net app with a directory name invalid

Tags: c#, citrix, unc

I have a .net application in c# running as an app from Citrix, and has an important function where it's supposed to write a text file to a specified UNC path on the network (ie. \COLL-INT\req\ ).  This works as desired from a desktop, but when attempting to do the same thing as a citrix app, the error message that returns is "The directory name \COLL-INT\req\ is invalid."  I checked the shared properties and it's indeed shared out to everyone and domain users and even myself as the domain administrator.  Anything else I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely to be anything you're doing wrong with your app, and likely to be something specific about the setup of your Citrix servers. Are your Citrix servers in a different domain to your desktop? If they're in a different domain you'll either need the fully qualified domain name of the machine hosting the share or the IP address.

Try getting the IP address of the machine hosting the share and see if you can reference the share from the Citrix server using the IP, e.g. \\10.1.1.1\shareName

Also try publishing Explorer from your Citrix server. Then from published Explorer see if you can access the same share. I would expect to see the same error you get from your app.